# Running TortoiseGit in Mac and Linux using wine

Tags: git, tortoisegit

TortoiseGit is a great GUI to handle your git projects through in use of contextual menu directly in the file explorer.

It gives support for the most common git commands, it's open source, it's free and it requires no signing up.

Nevertheless they give support only for Windows. Usually it's not a big problem since it's possible to run Windows programs in Mac and Linux using Wine. A tutorial about how to run Windows programs using wine may be found [here](https://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/).

The problem arises with the contextual menu of TortoiseGit since it doesn't connect with the file explorer of Mac.

Does anybody know how to run TortoiseGit in Mac o Linux using wine and getting around of the contextual menu or invoke this menu in some other way using Wine?

I know there are other Mac options for having a git GUI in Mac or Linux. But TortoiseGit is really great and I think it would be an advantage to have the same GUI for working in Windows as well for working in Mac or Linux since it wouldn't be necessary to learn two GUIs. In addition, some Mac GUIs are not as complete as TortoiseGit

**UPDATE:**

wine no longer works with newer versions of OSX. Now the unique way to run tortoise in Mac would be to install windows in a virtual machine such as Virtualbox and access to your Mac folders using a network drive (it runs with widows 7 to save resources). The good new is that you will no longer have trouble in accessing to the contextual menu and all functions will work. The bad new is that icons in the file explorer won't show because the mac directories will be accessed as a network drive. Of course you can know the changes in the directory using "check for modifications".

Comment: 1. TortoiseGit isn’t an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) at all. 2. TortoiseSVN is great but TortoiseGit IMHO keeps thinking the SVN way although it runs Git. Therefore I stopped using it even on Windows. There are better tools for Git.

Comment: @Melebius, could you please tell us which tools you know better that TortoiseGit for Windows as well for Mac?

Comment: Thank you @Melebius for pointing out the misuse of the IDE word, I did the correction.

Comment: I am OK with the default `git gui` and `gitk` and do the rest using command line. Since I haven’t been able to run these GUI tools on Mac OS X 10.6, I also discovered [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) to be a viable alternative. It supports more operations but is slower.

Comment: In my opinion, TortoiseGit is unparalleled in many aspects, even in 2022. I had to switch to MacOS and dearly miss the old turtle. I've been using GitKraken for a while now, since it's got a decent merge/rebase/conflict-resolving mechanism, but it can't reach Tortoise in that regard. It lacks other Tortoise features like the repo browser where you can freely navigate branches, compare individual files across branches easily etc. I've tried the VS Code git client, SourceTree and GitKraken and I'd prefer Tortoise. (I do use git CLI mostly, but for complex tasks, I prefer to use a nice GUI)

Comment: Thank you Loopmode for your comment. I was thinking trying or even purchasing Kraken since it the best of all paid git gui. It good to know to continue with tortoise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of ways of including the context menu in Wine. However, the TortoiseGit commands can be directly invoked such as `TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:[COMMAND] /path:[PATH]` (you can also use more *nix style command line parameters and use `-` instead of `/`).

The list of commands and further parameters can be found here: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-automation.html

I don't know how to call *nix `git` from TortoiseGit in Wine, but you should be aware, that, if you use Git for WIndows on Wine, there might be issues regarding EOL normalization or path translation problems.

Comment: Where did you find TortoiseGitProc.exe? Should I install on windows and get the file from there?

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing RabbitVCS as an alternative.
It gives you contextual menu directly in the file explorer.

Comment: It seems to be it's only for Linux

Comment: this is actually pretty similar to TurtoiseGit, can recommend! also works for Dolphin, Nautilus, etc

Answer (score 0):

It would be far more fruitful to utilize another application that supports your specific operating system.  There are a lot of reasons for this, but two off the top of my head:

- You incur significant risk of data corruption when attempting to intermingle applications which aren't supported
- Any security vulnerabilities with Git (yes, they do happen) would leave you exposed in two ways; one with your emulated GUI tool and one with your native Git application

I would encourage you to *instead* look at other tools that support your OS.